# Clicking "Run" in XCode runs my command line app, but the console windows does not appear

Tags: xcode

Well, the title pretty much sums it up, really. I've only just started toying around with XCode and stumbled upon this while coding the obligatory "Hello, World" app. When I click "Build And Run" (or just Run), my app *runs*, but XCode doesn't bring up the console window, so I can't, for example, see its output.

If I double-click the executable on the Detail View list, the terminal window appears as expected.

I suspect I'm doing something stupid, but don't know yet what it is. I'm running XCode 3.2.2 on Snow Leopard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

⌘-, select debugging, and change the "on start" value to "Show console & Debugger."

You can choose the other options, depending on your style.  See the [debugging guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/010-Debugging_Essentials/debugging_essentials.html) for more details.

-S!

Comment: I was expecting a normal terminal window, but the Debugging Console will do as well. Thanks.

Comment: The debugging console allows you to use (gdb) commands and will print out all "terminal" output.  Should be enough for debugging during the run of your app.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support terminal ANSI codes.  It would be nice to launch it in a proper terminal window, if, for example, you want to output coloured text.  Or at least, filter out the ANSI codes.